# Repeated capturing groups in regex when only last match is allowed (workaround)

Tags: regex

I got an string like

```
*hello world,hello2 world2,hello3 world3,..., helloN worldN *
```

I want to match repitedly hello worlds and capture only hello words in a global (/g) level for a multiline string, where that pattern is founf occasionally

If I define a repeated group with hello captured  `*(?:(\w+)\s\w+,?)+*` only the last helloN is matched due to http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

If I define a capturing group looking for the repeated hellos `*((\w+)+)*` Then my problem is that the match is not done, as it is checking against `*hello world,hello2 world2,hello3 world3*` or everything within two asterisks with that pattern

The result should be

```
- hello hello2 hello3 ... hello n
```

I think the key is finding a way to force to match the repeating group whereas the captured group is returning multiple outputs

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what's your issue... Why not use `g` and return the first capturing group of each match, [like so](http://regex101.com/r/dS9cY7)? What language are you using?

Comment: Robin, asterisks are part of the match, please revert them back :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were trying to bold your code.

Comment: Because I am using a more complicated pattern which includes lookaheads and lookbehinds, and I need to repeat capturing within asterisks (ok, it's just a sample, asterisks are not asterisks in my complex query). Take into account number of hellow worlds is dynamic

Comment: Please give more context (language, what you want to do generally speaking and with the rest of the pattern...), right now it's hard to get an idea of what constraints you have (+[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). There is no way to "remember" the value of a capturing group: its previous value is replaced each time it matches, so you'll need a workaround. Also, `*` might not be the best choice to say "something there" as it has a regex meaning :)

Comment: Like everyone else has asked you: what language are you using? Some support repeated capture groups, but most do not.

Comment: I am using vertica database, but so far any regex101 regex has worked there. I know some don't support repeated groups, but I am trying to resolve the workaround of the second try, capturing  something like *((\w+)+)* but here my problem is matching, I wonder if here there is some solution

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
(?<=[,*])(\w+)(?=\s\w+[,*])
```

see [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mG1eD9)

Comment: Sorry, but I'd like to get a solution to solve repeating captured groups, since that is a simplification of a more complex query (which already uses lookaheads and lookbehinds)